# How do you allow most of a jsf page to load while the backing bean is loading data?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page with a `p:datatable` that includes a column for server names (`p:outputLabel`) and a column for status (`p:graphicImage`).
The server names are hard-coded and returned quickly.  The status of the server takes about 10 seconds to return.  I would like the page to load everything, included the datatable with the server names populated, and also have a loading icon in place of the status icon until the status is found.  Once the backing bean completes the status check, I would want the datatable to refresh with the status found in the bean.

I thought using the `lazy` attribute in `p:datatable` would work but that appears to be more for pagination.
I only have 10 servers, so pagination is not necessary.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You could load with the loadingIcon by default then use `p:remoteCommand` to fetch the server status in the background and update each icon and you get a status back.

Comment: i'll add to Melloware's answer, read about Primefaces selectors. Make wrapper span with some "dummy" CSS class, like span class="dummyClass", and in remote command say update=@(.dummyClass). Inside that span you can have loading icon (rendered=#{not row.fetched}) and some real data (rendered=#{row.fetched}. Just an idea.

Comment: P.S. This way you will update only Cell content, and only in desired column

Comment: You could try https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/outputPanel.xhtml